# php nested foreach not working

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, php-mongodb

```
   //connects to mongo
   $collection  = (new MongoDB\Client)->mfrmls->properties;

   //takes array with data from array of objects            
   foreach ($obj as $k => $v){

    //prints to make sure on the right record.  this works fine
    echo "object {$v['ListingId']} \n";

    // creates a query to the mongo DB, which works fine, i have checked via var_dump
    $cursor = $collection->find(['ListingId'  => $v['ListingId']]);

    //this for each will never print anything it just seems to be skipped.
    //if i take it out of the nested foreach it works fine.
    foreach($cursor as $document) {
            echo "no no \n";
            }
    }
```

the results I get are :

```
object G4849756 
object A4202291 
object O5548422 
object O5548513 
object D5921405
```

which is clearly missing the second for loop echo.

just for reference. "$cursor" only gets called once the foreach statement runs, i guess this is just how mongoDB - PHP works.

Comment: Try adding a `var_dump($cursor);` right after setting it to find out what's really in it. I'm also thinking _maybe_ (I'd have to confirm) you may need to convert it from a _obect_ to an _array_ before you can use `foreach` on it. Not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` only iterates over array.
You can check what data type of `$cursor` by using `var_dump($cursor);`

Comment: its a object, MongoDB\Driver\Cursor Object ( [database] => mfrmls [collection] => properties [query] => MongoDB\Driver\Query Object

Answer (score 1):

Your code missing some checks. try this:

```
//connects to mongo
   $collection  = (new MongoDB\Client)->mfrmls->properties;

   //takes array with data from array of objects            
   foreach ($obj as $k => $v){

    //prints to make sure on the right record.  this works fine
    echo "object {$v['ListingId']} \n";

    // creates a query to the mongo DB, which works fine, i have checked via  
    $cursor = $collection->find(['ListingId'  => $v['ListingId']]);
print_r( $cursor);
    //this for each will never print anything it just seems to be skipped.
    //if i take it out of the nested foreach it works fine.
    if((is_array($cursor) || is_object($cursor)) && !empty( $cursor)) {
       foreach($cursor as $document) {
            echo "no no \n";
            }
     }
    }
```

Comment: `MongoDB\Driver\Cursor Object
(
    [database] => mfrmls
    [collection] => properties
    [query] => MongoDB\Driver\Query Object
        (
            [filter] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ListingId] => D5921405
                )

            [options] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [serverId] => 1
                )

            [readConcern] => 
        )

`

Comment: should have no issue with this type of object.

Comment: echo something in else condition and check, Is it coming in foreach or not ?